# user with email having "-" symbol is not created in aspnetusers table and no error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using EF code first approach. When I create a user with email id containing "-" symbol, it doesnot create the user.Even it didn't throw any error or exception.But the user is created with valid email(without "-" symbol)

Comment: mark xplore what is the problem..u need to display error message? you tried anything ?

Comment: I need to know why the user is not created with email id having "-" symbol.Upto my walk around after this line executed "await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);" user is not created.user is a entity having email property have value like "mark-clark@gg.com"

Comment: it will create with "-" symbol

Comment: actually the user is not created with that mail id

Answer (score 0):

Have you customized the default login system in any way? By default if you create an asp.net mvc 5 web project with the default login system it allows you to have a hyphen in the email address just fine:

[Standard Login System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC5AF.png)

[Standard Login System Database Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IlC3.png)